# Predicate Statement Equivalency

Tags: proof-writing, predicate-logic

I was wondering what the difference between these 2 predicate statements were and if they were equivalent or not.

$$
\forall x\in \Bbb N   \ \exists y \in \Bbb N:  \ \neg P(x) \implies P(y) \ \land Q(x,y)
$$

and

$$
\forall x\in \Bbb N  :\ \neg P(x) \implies \ \exists y \in \Bbb N :\ P(y) \land Q(x,y)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are equivalent.

It is an instance of one of the Prenex Laws that state how you can move quantifiers around in a predicate logic statement.

In this case, the relevant Prenex Law is:

$\psi \to \exists x \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\psi \to \varphi(x))$

where $\varphi(x)$ is any formula that has $x$ as a free variable, but with $\psi$ as a formula that does *not* have any free variables $x$.

In your case, we have that $\neg P(x)$ does not have any free variable $y$, and hence we can apply this Prenex Law to show that

$$\exists y \in \Bbb N:  \ \neg P(x) \implies P(y) \ \land Q(x,y)$$

and

$$\neg P(x) \implies \ \exists y \in \Bbb N :\ P(y) \land Q(x,y)$$

are equivalent, meaning that

$$
\forall x\in \Bbb N   \ \exists y \in \Bbb N:  \ \neg P(x) \implies P(y) \ \land Q(x,y)
$$

and

$$
\forall x\in \Bbb N  :\ \neg P(x) \implies \ \exists y \in \Bbb N :\ P(y) \land Q(x,y)
$$

are equivalent as well.

Comment: It would be not equivalent if it was for all x and for all y?

Comment: @James It also works for the for all. That is, another Prenex Law says that $\psi \to \forall x \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi \to \varphi(x))$

Comment: I see! thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey I just wanted to know what the negation of the first equation would turn out to be.

Comment: @james $\exists x (P(x) \land \forall y (P(y) \to \neg Q(x,y)))$ ie there is some prime not divisible by any prime